# want to read all IRsignal when hold button on remote

Tags: python, esp32, micropython

```
def read_ircode(ird):
    wait_ir = 1
    complete_ir = 0
    seq0_ir = []
    seq1_ir = []

    while wait_ir == 1:
        if ird.value() == 0:
            wait_ir = 0
    while wait_ir == 0 and complete_ir == 0:
        start = utime.ticks_us()
        while ird.value() == 0:
            ms1 = utime.ticks_us()
        diff = utime.ticks_diff(ms1,start)
        seq0_ir.append(diff)
        while ird.value() == 1 and complete_ir == 0:
            ms2 = utime.ticks_us()
            diff = utime.ticks_diff(ms2,ms1)
            if diff > 10000:
                complete_ir = 1
        seq1_ir.append(diff)

    code = ""
    for val in seq1_ir:
        if val < 2000:
            if val < 700:
                code += "L"
            else:
                code += "H"
    command = ""
    for k,v in act_code.items():
        if code == v:
            command = k
    if command == "":
        command = code
    return command
```

When i hold the button the result just give me a 1 time
i just want when i hd old button then show me all time i hol

[image]

i just want when i hd old button then show me all time i hold
[image]
i just want result like this